# Adding a colorbar and a line to multiple imshow() plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have this source code:

```
idx=0
b=plt.psd(dOD[:,idx],Fs=self.fs,NFFT=512)
B=np.zeros((2*len(self.Chan),len(b[0])))
B[idx,:]=20*log10(b[0])

c=plt.psd(dOD_filt[:,idx],Fs=self.fs,NFFT=512)
C=np.zeros((2*len(self.Chan),len(b[0])))
C[idx,:]=20*log10(c[0])

for idx in range(2*len(self.Chan)):
    b=plt.psd(dOD[:,idx],Fs=self.fs,NFFT=512)
    B[idx,:]=20*log10(b[0])

    c=plt.psd(dOD_filt[:,idx],Fs=self.fs,NFFT=512)
    C[idx,:]=20*log10(c[0])

## Calculate the color scaling for the imshow()    
aux1 = max(max(B[i,:]) for i in range(size(B,0)))
aux2 = min(min(B[i,:]) for i in range(size(B,0)))
bux1 = max(max(C[i,:]) for i in range(size(C,0)))
bux2 = min(min(C[i,:]) for i in range(size(C,0)))
scale1 = 0.75*max(aux1,bux1)
scale2 = 0.75*min(aux2,bux2)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1,figsize=(7,7))#,sharey='True')
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.24, hspace=0.35)

ii=find(c[1]>frange)[0]

## Making the plots
cax=axes[0].imshow(B, origin = 'lower',vmin=scale2,vmax=scale1)
axes[0].set_ylim((0,2*len(self.Chan)))
axes[0].set_xlabel(' Frequency (Hz) ')
axes[0].set_ylabel(' Channel Number ') 
axes[0].set_title('Pre-Filtered')
cax2=axes[1].imshow(C, origin = 'lower',vmin=scale2,vmax=scale1)
axes[1].set_ylim(0,2*len(self.Chan))
axes[1].set_xlabel(' Frequency (Hz) ')
axes[1].set_ylabel(' Channel Number ')
axes[1].set_title('Post-Filtered')

axes[0].annotate('690nm', xy=((ii+1)/2, len(self.Chan)/2-1), 
        xycoords='data', va='center', ha='right')
axes[0].annotate('830nm', xy=((ii+1)/2, len(self.Chan)*3/2-1 ), 
        xycoords='data', va='center', ha='right')
axes[1].annotate('690nm', xy=((ii+1)/2, len(self.Chan)/2-1), 
        xycoords='data', va='center', ha='right')
axes[1].annotate('830nm', xy=((ii+1)/2, len(self.Chan)*3/2-1 ), 
        xycoords='data', va='center', ha='right')


axes[0].axis('tight')
axes[1].axis('tight')

## Set up the xlim to aprox frange Hz
axes[0].set_xlim(left=0,right=ii)
axes[1].set_xlim(left=0,right=ii)

## Make the xlabels become the actual frequency number
tickslabel=np.zeros((ii))
ticks = r_[0:ii:5]
tickslabel = linspace(0.,2.,size(ticks))
axes[0].set_xticks(ticks)
axes[0].set_xticklabels(tickslabel)
axes[1].set_xticks(ticks)
axes[1].set_xticklabels(tickslabel)


## Draw a line to separate the two different wave lengths, and name each region
l1 = Line2D([0,ii],[28,10],ls=':',color='black')                                    
axes[0].add_line(l1)
axes[1].add_line(l1)
```

This code generates this figure:
[image: The ploted Figure]

The fixed code to make the xticks looks properly are already inside the code, and the new plot is also shown.

How can I add a single colorbar (and give it a title) to both this subplots? (they are at same scale)
This colorbar should occupy the whole left side of the figure.

Inside the code there`s a place I try to draw a line in both figures (at the same place), but none of those are shown. Why is that?

If you need any more information about my code (like the size of the data entered, just ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ticks variable appears to be all zeros:

```
ticks=np.zeros((ii))
```

but it should enumerate X locations (in axis coordinates) where you'd like the tick marks to go.  When you call set_xticklabels, the list gives the text to show for each tick.

Here's a simple example showing how xlim, set_xticks, and set_xticklabels interact:

```
from pylab import *
x = arange(128*128).reshape((128,128))
matshow(x)
xlim(right=64)
# xticks: where the xticks should go (indexes into x's columns)
xticks = r_[0:64:25]
gca().set_xticks(xticks)
# labels: text to show for each element of xticks
#    here, we apply a multiplier just to show how the
#    labels can differ from the xticks.
labels = ['%.1f' % (x,) for x in xticks * pi / 2]
gca().set_xticklabels(labels)
show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you need to have the xticks not be zeros. You could use something like

```
xticks = linspace(0.,2.,5)
```

which will give you 5 points between 0.0 and 2.0. To get a color bar use

```
fig.colorbar()
```

which is demonstrated at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html 
Since the data has the same scale, adding a colorbar for either set of data should do the trick for you, but you might have to adjust its placement.

Comment: My problem is more about adjusting the place of the colorbar rather than adding it. I want to have a single colobar (of the size of both plots) on the right side of them. I dont have a clue how to do this with the subplot instnace.